# What is Number after symbol in Android Tombstone backtrace?

Tags: android, debugging, backtrace, tombstone

I was reading Tombstone in Android which have backtrace

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_angler/angler:7.1.1/NYC/enh12211018:eng/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 17946, tid: 17949, name: crasher  >>> crasher <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc
    r0 0000000c  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
    r4 00000000  r5 0000000c  r6 eccdd920  r7 00000078
    r8 0000461a  r9 ffc78c19  sl ab209441  fp fffff924
    ip ed01b834  sp eccdd800  lr ecfa9a1f  pc ecfd693e  cpsr 600e0030

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0004793e  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+1)
    #01 pc 0001aa1b  /system/lib/libc.so (readdir+10)
    #02 pc 00001b91  /system/xbin/crasher (readdir_null+20)
    #03 pc 0000184b  /system/xbin/crasher (do_action+978)
    #04 pc 00001459  /system/xbin/crasher (thread_callback+24)
    #05 pc 00047317  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
    #06 pc 0001a7e5  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+34)
Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
```

But I am confused what does `pthread_mutex_lock+1` and `readdir+10` Number after function symbol means?

Source - https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the offset of the code location respective to the start of the function.

As an example, `readdir+10` indicates that the call was made from the tenth byte in the `readdir` function.

Comment: It shouldn't be Line because in my backtrace i see +503 but the function is not having 503 lines. I think it should be bytes in memory.

Comment: @RahulAN - thanks for spotting my typo/thinko. I edited the answer to correct it.